# Sorting by priority

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, priority-queue

I need your help with sorting applying some rules.

I am using nestjs with prisma, I have these two models.

```
model Prayer {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  title       String
  description String
  dueDate     DateTime?
  ongoing     Boolean
  answered    Boolean   @default(false)
  userId      Int
  contactId   Int?
  user        User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  contact     Contact?  @relation(fields: [contactId], references: [id])
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
}
```

and

```
model Note {
  id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  title        String
  content      String
  userId       Int
  contactId    Int
  reminderDate DateTime?
  ongoing      Boolean?
  user         User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  contact      Contact   @relation(fields: [contactId], references: [id])
  createdAt    DateTime  @default(now())
}
```

I need to create some logic to do this:

- Consider both notes (Note) and prayers (Prayer) on the same level.
- Priority starts with elements that have "ongoing" set to true.
- If there are more than 2 elements with "ongoing" set to true, proceed to validate by the closest reminder date ("reminderDate" or "dueDate" as applicable).
- If there are no elements with "ongoing" set to true, also evaluate by the reminder date ("reminderDate" or "dueDate").
- If there are more than 2 elements despite the previous validations, proceed to validate by "createdAt."
- If you still haven't selected 2 elements, also prioritize by the closest creation date ("createdAt").
- Return the resulting 2 elements, either a combination of notes and prayers or just notes or just prayers.

I have created a class named UserFeed:

```
import { Note, Prayer } from '@prisma/client';

export class UserFeed {
  notes: Note[];
  prayers: Prayer[];
}
```

I have this

```
async getFeed(user: CurrentUser) {
    const allNotes = await this.prisma.note.findMany({
      where: {
        userId: user.sub,
      },
    });

    const allPrayers = await this.prisma.prayer.findMany({
      where: {
        userId: user.sub,
      },
    });

    const userFeed: UserFeed = this.applyPriorityAndSelection(
      allNotes,
      allPrayers,
    );

    return userFeed;
  }

  private applyPriorityAndSelection(
    notes: Note[],
    prayers: Prayer[],
  ): UserFeed {
    const feedDTO: UserFeed = { notes: [], prayers: [] };

    // Paso 1: Filtrar elementos con ongoing = true
    const ongoingNotes = notes.filter((note) => note.ongoing === true);
    const ongoingPrayers = prayers.filter((prayer) => prayer.ongoing === true);

    // Paso 2: Ordenar elementos con ongoing = true por reminderDate o dueDate más cercana
    ongoingNotes.sort((a, b) => {
      const dateA = a.reminderDate || a.createdAt;
      const dateB = b.reminderDate || b.createdAt;
      return dateB.getTime() - dateA.getTime();
    });

    ongoingPrayers.sort((a, b) => {
      const dateA = a.dueDate || a.createdAt;
      const dateB = b.dueDate || b.createdAt;
      return dateB.getTime() - dateA.getTime();
    });

    // Paso 3: Tomar los primeros 2 elementos con ongoing = true
    feedDTO.notes = ongoingNotes.slice(0, 2);
    feedDTO.prayers = ongoingPrayers.slice(0, 2);

    // Paso 4: Si no se han seleccionado 2 elementos con ongoing = true, ordenar por createdAt más cercano
    if (feedDTO.notes.length < 2) {
      const remainingNotes = notes.filter(
        (note) => !ongoingNotes.includes(note),
      );
      remainingNotes.sort(
        (a, b) => b.createdAt.getTime() - a.createdAt.getTime(),
      );
      feedDTO.notes.push(...remainingNotes.slice(0, 2 - feedDTO.notes.length));
    }

    if (feedDTO.prayers.length < 2) {
      const remainingPrayers = prayers.filter(
        (prayer) => !ongoingPrayers.includes(prayer),
      );
      remainingPrayers.sort(
        (a, b) => b.createdAt.getTime() - a.createdAt.getTime(),
      );
      feedDTO.prayers.push(
        ...remainingPrayers.slice(0, 2 - feedDTO.prayers.length),
      );
    }

    return feedDTO;
  }
```

But that gives me something like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "feed": {
      "notes": [
        {
          "id": "45",
          "ongoing": true,
          "reminderDate": null,
          "createdAt": "2023-09-14T23:07:03.399Z"
        },
        {
          "id": "47",
          "ongoing": false,
          "reminderDate": null,
          "createdAt": "2023-09-14T23:18:13.385Z"
        }
      ],
      "prayers": [
        {
          "id": 32,
          "ongoing": true,
          "dueDate": null,
          "createdAt": "2023-09-12T23:53:38.617Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 29,
          "ongoing": true,
          "dueDate": null,
          "createdAt": "2023-09-12T23:42:51.929Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I need only two objects, not two of each.

Any Ideas?